# Symfony filesystem ACLs on ZFS

Tags: symfony, zfs

I'm writing Symfony2-based sites on a Ubuntu 12.04 server, with the code itself hosted on a ZFS filesystem partition/zpool. However, the instructions on the [Symfony 2 installation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) for setting ACLs on the directories (app/logs & app/cache) do not apply, because ZFS does not support the `chmod +a` or `setfacl` commands.

Is there a ZFS-compatible version of the below commands?

```
sudo setfacl -Rn -m u:"$APACHEUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dRn -m u:"$APACHEUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Answer (score 2):

ZFS supports acls. You can set them using `chmod A+`, which looks something like:

```
chmod A+user:alister:add_file:allow /path/to/dir
```

Have a look at [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/marks/entry/zfs_acls).

To mimic the `setfacl` commands, you'll at least need the following permissions:

- read_data
- write_data
- add_file
- add_subdirectory
- delete_child
- file_inherit
- dir_inherit

The commands would look like this:

```
chmod A+user:`whoami`:read_data/write_data/add_file/add_subdirectory/delete_child:file_inherit/dir_inherit:allow app/cache app/logs
chmod A+user:"$APACHEUSER":read_data/write_data/add_file/add_subdirectory/delete_child:file_inherit/dir_inherit:allow app/cache app/logs
```

I've gathered this from the article I mentioned, but have no experience with ZFS, so you might need to tweak the commands a bit.

Comment: So what would be the invocation to allow the www-data user to create files & directories, like the above?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm not sure it will actually work, but you'll have something to start with.

Comment: Whatever ACLs I use, such as the simple "A+user:www-data:add_file:allow'", it give "chmod: invalid mode" According to http://serverfault.com/a/500199/181 they are not supported on ZFS on Linux - or if they are, not the version I have installed (ZFS pool 28, filesystem 5, according to a man page version)